# How large can a set of pairwise disjoint 2-(7,3,1) designs (Fano planes) be?

Tags: combinatorics, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, combinatorial-designs, finite-geometry

As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) defines well, the Fano plane is a small symmetric block design, specifically a 2-(7,3,1)-design. The points of the design are the points of the plane, and the blocks of the design are the lines of the plane.

[image: an example of Fano plane with 7 number]

Now what I'm trying to find is the number of different Fano plane with points labeled $1$ to $7$. By "different" I mean every set of blocks should be disjoint from every other; that no two planes have common blocks.

Put another way, I want to know how large a set of Fano planes can be if the sets of lines are pairwise disjoint.

Every Fano plane has 7 blocks and here I listed all the blocks you could see in the picture:

\begin{align*}
\{6, 4, 3\} \\
\{3, 2, 5\} \\
\{5, 1, 6\} \\
\{6, 7, 2\} \\
\{3, 7, 1\} \\
\{5, 7, 4\} \\
\{1, 4, 2\} \\
\end{align*}

Please use a combinatorial approach, not groups and algebra.

Comment: I assume two arrangements are considered equivalent (and count just as one) if the set of blocks in one matches that in the other, right?

Comment: have you tried some coding ?

Comment: @Agawa001 actually no. Because here I need the method to count them the number is not really important to me!.... by the way it is a good method to check the accuracy of the solution....thank you

Comment: @Niloofar_jz as long as i have time, i will give it a try, seems a strongly sophisticated form standing behind it

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be familiar with the automorphism/collineation group the the Fano plane, would you? If you know it has order $168$, it's not hard to count non isomorphic Fano planes. But that pushes the difficulty to getting the $168$, if you're not already familiar.

Comment: (Also, I assume by "not having common blocks" I assume you mean that the two sets of blocks are different. Non isomorphic Fano Ames *can* share blocks; several, even).

Comment: @Agawa001 But the code has It's complexity too; I should obtain every permutation of the numbers 1 to 7 in the Fano plane and get 7 block from that new Fano then check every blocks of that to previous Fano blocks(if it has common blocks put it away else save that Fano in a List of disered Fanos that every new fanos will check to them)... If I calculated correct the time complexity is exponential which is not gonna be work in laptop!

Comment: @Niloofar_jz: You need to explain what you mean by "has common blocks". Do two planes count as the same only if _all_ their blocks are the same, or is a single block in common between two planes enough that you don't want both planes in your collection?

Comment: @pjs36 I know about automorphism and  isomorphic especially in Fano But yes I don't have any other  algebraic approach to carry on with that...
Yes every Fano sets of blocks must be different from  the other Fanos....
Thanks..

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes, it's evidently too early for me. I think I meant to say "nonequivalent" instead, thank you (I believe that's the word that's used)

Comment: @Niloofar_jz: You STILL haven't explained what you mean by "sets of blocks must be different from the other". To be concrete, if we take your figure and swap the numbers 3 and 4, do we then **(a)** get a new plane that you want to count (because 123 is in the new one but not the old one), or **(b)** get something you don't want to count separately because both of them contain 156?

Comment: @HenningMakholm (b)  is correct a new Fano is accepted if and only if ALL the sets be different from previous Fano....
thank you for your making clear...

Comment: @ Morgan Rodgers I know It's constant!  but assume we already build all 7*7! Fanos sets of block; we should check all the blocks to each other in worst case which It's mean 7^7! which It is really big.....but if we check one fano to previous one and put it away if It wont be totally different we have more chance to check less cases....am I right??.... Thank you :)

Comment: @MorganRodgers yeah the cases are fewer because all blocks we have are $\binom {7} {3} = 35 $ which means at most we have 35/7  = 5 different Fanos !

Answer (score 4):

Any set of two pairwise disjoint Fano planes is maximal; three or more Fano Planes must share at least one line. Henning's answer is streets ahead in terms of succinctness (and quite clever to boot), but frankly, I didn't do all of this work *not* to post an answer :)

---

But before I launch into a tedious case-by-case proof that there do not exist $3$ or more pairwise-disjoint Fano planes I would like to talk a bit about what I dream might yield a nicer approach for a someone with more insight than me (possibly my future self).

It is fairly well known that any pair of Fano planes share exactly $0, 1$ or $3$ lines (in fact, I found today that each Fano plane is disjoint from exactly $8$ others, shares a single line with exactly $14$ others, and shares $3$ lines with exactly $7$ others).

To quote a passage from Buckard Polsters [article](http://www.qedcat.com/articles/yea.pdf), *YEA WHY TRY HER RAW WET HAT: A Tour of the Smallest Projective Space*,

> There is a unique partition of the $30$ labelled Fano planes
>   into $2$ sets $X$ and $Y$ of 15 each such that any $2$ Fano planes
>   in $1$ of the sets have exactly $1$ line in common.

You can take the $15$ single-intersection planes and make a nice picture of something called a generalized quadrangle from them (this one's "the doily", also from his article)

[image: Doily from Polster]

whose points are all labeled Fano planes and whose lines are Lines the planes share (there's a big picture in the pdf showing the planes). It's obviously silent on pairs of planes that are disjoint, but I'd like to believe there's some insight to be gained by considering how the two partitions interact with each other. As a sidenote, the article is both very informative and quite fun to read.

---

The usual definition is that two Fano planes are considered *equivalent* if they have the same set of lines. Under this definition, there are $30$ non-equivalent Fano planes that we'll arbitrarily separate into one of two categories:

[image: fundamentally different planes]

The first do not contain the line $\{1,2,3\}$ and there are $4! = 24$ of these. The second do contain the line $\{1,2,3\}$ and there are $3! = 6$ of these.

Let us now find pairwise disjoint (those sharing no lines) Fano planes. We'll search in the first category of planes, those not containing the line $\{1,2,3\}$. I find it more convenient to use the set $\{1,2,3,x,y,z,w\}$ instead of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ as point labels.

Without loss of generality, we will start with the plane

[image: starting plane]

whose lines are

\begin{array}{ccc}
12x & 13y & 23z\\
1zw & 2yw & 3xw\\
&xyz&
\end{array}

and attempt to find a disjoint plane by permuting $\{x, y, z, w\}$. Such a permutation must have no fixed points: if $x$ did not move, the line $12x$ would be preserved (and similarly for $y$ and $z$), while if $w$ were fixed, the line $xyz$ would be preserved.

Thus our permutation is either a $4$-cycle ($a \mapsto b \mapsto c \mapsto d \mapsto a$), or a product of disjoint $2$-cycles, as these are the only permutations of $4$ letters with no fixed points.

The list of products of disjoint $2$-cycles is rather small

\begin{align*}x \leftrightarrow y &\text{ and } z \leftrightarrow w \\
x \leftrightarrow z &\text{ and } y \leftrightarrow w \\
x \leftrightarrow w &\text{ and } y \leftrightarrow z
\end{align*}

and for each, one of the lines containing $w$ is preserved (e.g., for $x \leftrightarrow y \text{ and } z \leftrightarrow w$, the line $1zw$). Thus we must use some $4$-cycle to permute the letters, and without loss of generality, we may choose $x \mapsto y \mapsto z \mapsto w \mapsto x$, yielding the plane

[image]

with lines
\begin{array}{ccc}
12w & 13x & 23y\\
1yz & 2xz & 3zw\\
&xyw&
\end{array}

which is easily seen to be disjoint from our starting plane.

Now we attempt to add a third plane, one that still avoids the line $\{1,2,3\}$. We have enough lines to avoid that it's best to keep them in mind, and attempt to place $x, y, z, w$ around the restrictions:

[image: possibilities]

In the picture, the green letters are the only possible values for a certain spot (we can't have $x$ in the line with $1$ and $2$, since we've already used the line $12x$, and so on, for the straight lines). The fact that the two circles have been lines $xyz$ and $xyw$ means that we can't use both $x$ and $y$ in the circular line. Thus, each point has two possibilities. By making a single choice, the rest of the points are completely determined.

Alas, neither choice has a happy ending:

[image: no good]

So to recap, we've only managed to find a pitiful pair of disjoint Fano planes from the $24$ that avoid the line $\{1,2,3\}$. But maybe we can find a plane containing $\{1,2,3\}$ that's disjoint from ours (spoiler alert: We cannot).

Using the template above (but $x, y, z, w$ instead of $4, 5, 6, 7$) for a plane containing $\{1,2,3\}$, we write possibilities for the three to-be-labeled points in green. We also have the same Forbidden lines from our two disjoint planes.

[image: no good 2: the ungoodening]

Using each of the Forbidden lines with two letters (e.g., $2$ can't go at the top because the line $2yw$ has already been used), we are able to narrow down the possibilities.

But, to our shared dismay, $2$ is needed in two places, and we cannot find another Fano plane, disjoint from our two. As we have been working in full generality, no set of two disjoint Fano planes can be expanded to a set of three or more pairwise disjoint Fano planes.

Comment: I think the quote from Polster actually settles it immediately: Once you have picked one plane from the $X$ set and one plane from the $Y$ set, every remaining plane is in either $X$ or $Y$, so it necessarily shares a line with at least one of the planes already selected.

Comment: @Henning I think you're right. I initially wasn't quite sure (and still am not) whether a pair from *either* partition would share just $1$ line (or instead if all the $0$ and $3$ sharing was happening within a single partition). But I think you're right, which does indeed give a maximum of two disjoint as an immediate corollary!

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to make more than **two** Fano planes on the same seven points that don't share any line.

If one of them is the standard numbering (where three points are collinear iff their bitwise XOR is 0):

```
    4
   1 2
    7
5   3   6
```

then the complete set of planes that are compatible with this (up to automorphisms of each plane) is

```
   3           3           3           3
  1 2         1 2         1 2         1 2
   5           4           7           6
6  4  7     7  5  6     4  6  5     5  7  4

   3           3           3           3
  1 2         1 2         1 2         1 2
   6           7           4           5
7  4  5     6  5  4     5  6  7     4  7  6
```

and every pair of these have a line in common.

The 8 compatible planes are enumerated by first selecting what the third point in the line containing 1,2 is (giving one of the four columns), then selecting what the third point in the line containing 3 and the previously chosen point (two choices possible since the corresponding line in the base plane must be avoided), and finally only one placement of the two remaining points is possible.

There's a symmetry to the arrangement: The compatible planes arise from the standard plane by applying a permuation with cycle type $1+1+2+3$ where the one of the transposed points is collinear with the two fixed points. Each compatible plane arises in $21$ ways by this construction, corresponding to $21$ choices of the two fixed points.

The above representations of the $8$ compatible planes correspond to composing the permutations $(3\,4)(5\,6\,7)$ and $(3\,4)(7\,6\,5)$ with each of the four automorphisms of the standard plane that stabilize $1$, $2$, and $3$.

Comment: With thanks to @pjs36 for pointing out several errors in my previous answer.

Comment: This is a very nice approach; definitely quite refined and a nice improvement! (And you flatter me: It was but a single error!)